# JS Find percentage of items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, percentage

So I have this array:

```
const colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'white']
```

I want to output the percentage of the similar items using JavaScript.

Such as blue and green should be 25% each, red 37.5% and white 12.5% out of total of 8(100%) items in the array.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Count the unique values and divide their quantity by the length of the array

Comment: I'd rather not give a complete answer with code because this sounds like a homework question. But I'll give you the steps. -

First, you'll want to assign the length of the array to a constant.

Then, for each unique color, you'll want to count how many times that color appears in the array. You can use array.filter for this. -

Finally, you'll want to divide the number of occurrences of each color by the length of the array, and that will give you the percentages.

Comment: Sorry guys, so my actual issue was I didn't know how to get the unique values from the array. that should've been my question.  Rob answered it thankfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will first need to find each unique color, then iterate over them to find how many there are.  Once you have this you can calculate the percentage as (num * 100 / total).

Take a look at this:

```js
const colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'white']

const totalItems = colors.length
const uniqueItems = [...new Set(colors)]
uniqueItems.forEach(currColor => {
  const numItems = colors.filter(color => color === currColor) 
  console.log(`color ${currColor} represents ${numItems.length * 100 / totalItems}%`)
})
/*
color blue represents 25%
color red represents 37.5%
color green represents 25%
color white represents 12.5%
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, so my actual question should've been how to find unique values from the array. Since I didn't know about Set() I wasn't able to work on the percentage but once I have the unique values along with the array length, rest is simple.

Comment: @Parsa You don't need a `Set` for this. Just take an object `{ blue: ..., red: ..., ... }`

Comment: FYI: If you are worried about performance, this answer is not good since there is a filter for each color.

Answer (score 2):

This can help:

```
const colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'white']

var data ={}

colors.map(el=>{
  if(!data[el]){
    return data[el]=colors.filter(ob=>ob===el).length*100/colors.length
     }
  })
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Why would you use a .map()?  Why not use .forEach()?

Comment: Okay, .map() was my first idea but I can try .forEach()

Comment: Thanks, yes this works as as well, with map i get an array returned which I can loop to display the percentages

Answer (score 2):

The other answers so far do this in multiple steps.  But it's fairly simple to do a single pass at the data using `reduce`, by noting that each instance add a fraction of `1 / array.length` and hence a percentage of `100 / array.length`.  Here's one technique:

```js
const percentages = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((pcts, x) => ({...pcts, [x]: (pcts [x] || 0) + 100 / (xs .length)}), {})

const colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'white']

console .log (percentages (colors))
```

Comment: Thank You Scott! I always appreciate seeing different approaches to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object as hash map and count the occurences. Thenget the entries of the hash map and return an array of colors and percent value.

```js
const
    colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'white'],
    percents = Object
        .entries(colors.reduce((map, color) => (map[color] = (map[color] || 0) + 1, map), {}))
        .map(([color, count]) => [color, count * 100 / colors.length]);

console.log(percents);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina! Good to see your approach too